# Having trouble removing part of an href after adding it

Tags: jquery, href, attr

I'm attempting to create a toggle that assigns a class and adds the id to the target href. I also want the ability to remove the contents of the `tags` variable from the href without removing the rest of the link.

My Issue:
Well, when I click a link, it correctly assigns it to the href, but when I click and already active link, it removes the class fine, but does not remove what was added to the href. For instance, if I click "construction" I get `http://bshoults.com/construction&` which is correct, but when I click it again, I get `http://bshoults.com/construction&construction&` instead of `http://bshoults.com`. The following code removes the entire href and not just the `construction&` portion.

http://jsfiddle.net/tewvd/1/

```
$('.tags li a').click(function() {

    // set variable to get the href of .button
    var _href = $('.button').attr("href");

    // if has class 'selected'
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {

        // remove class 'selected'
        $(this).removeClass('selected');

        // set variable to get tag from id of item
        var tags = ($(this).attr('id') + "&");

        // create link based on href and tags
        $('.button').removeAttr("href", tags);
    }
    // otherwise give it a class of 'selected'
    else {
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        // set variable to get tag from id of item
        var tags = ($(this).attr('id') + "&");

        // create link based on href and tags
        $('.button').attr("href", _href + tags);
    }
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="tags">
    <li><a href="javascript: void(0)" id="construction">construction</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript: void(0)" id="saturday">saturday</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript: void(0)" id="singles">singles</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript: void(0)" id="sunday+morning">sunday morning</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript: void(0)" id="teaching">teaching</a></li>
</ul>
<p><a href="http://bshoults.com/" class="button">Next Step &rarr;</a></p>
​
```

​

Comment: You are attempting.... ok... so keep trying? I do not see a problem here....

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add my issue...duh. Well, when I click a link, it correctly assigns it to the href, but when I click and already active link, it removes the class fine, but does not remove what was added to the href. For instance, if I click "construction" I get "http://bshoults.com/sunday+morning&" which is correct, but when I click it again, I get "http://bshoults.com/construction&construction&" instead of "http://bshoults.com"

Comment: your url's are not "correct urls" in the format of 
http://www.domainname.com/pagename.html?queryparam=value&otherquery=value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`removeAttr()` doesn't replace attribute text.  I just removes the whole attribute.

Where you have...

```
// create link based on href and tags
$('.button').removeAttr("href", tags);
```

...you need to have

```
$('.button').attr('href', $('.button').attr('href').replace(tags, ''));
```